# Error: Array required, but Vector<Double> found?

Tags: java, arrays, vector, constructor

I know vectors in Java are obsolete, I keep getting that warning, but we are supposed to used vectors, so I am.

This is what I am trying to make work:

The constructor, takes dimension n and sets all elements to 0: NVector(int n)

But I am getting an error saying "Array required, but Vector found."  Can anyone help me figure this out?

```
public class NVector
{

Vector<Double> v;
NVector(int n)
{
    v = new Vector(n);
    for(int i = 0; i<=n; i++)
    {
        v[i] = 0; //Error in this line 

    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Java the `[]` thing only works on arrays. You have to call `v.add(0)` to accomplish the same on a Vector.

See more functions for Vectors here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html

Answer (score 0):

```
v[i] = 0; //Error in this line
```

should be

```
v.add(0);
```

(*not* `v.set(i, 0);`, because the vector starts empty. The size you pass in the constructor is just a hint for efficiency.)

Vectors are *not* arrays, even though they can do similar things.

Also, using `Vector` is outdated advice. You should use `ArrayList` unless you have a particular need for something else.

Also, arrays aren't bad, if you know the size in advance. Arrays of primitive types (double, int, float, etc) in particular will be more efficient than ArrayLists. ArrayLists (and Vectors) are just easier to use if you don't know the size in advance. There are also other reasons you might use an ArrayList over an array - for example, the methods in the [Collections](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.htm) class don't work on arrays.

Comment: The vector is empty initially. Thus, it should be `v.add(i)` instead of `v.set(i, 0);`